# How to build multiple .py files into a single executable file using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have made a small PyQt application containing 5-6 .py files. Now I want to build and compile them into a single main file, meaning it has to operate from one main window exe.

My .py files are connected with each other successfully. I have used pyinstaller to make the executable file, but the problem is I built each .py file into its own .exe file. But I want to make a single .exe file through which all the .py files can be used.

How to build all .py files into a single .exe file?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: I want to deploy it to client machine and want to give only executable file.

Answer (score 53):

Suppose you had a file called **create.py** like

```
def square (num)
    return num ** 2
```

Another file in the same directory called **input.py**

```
from . import create
def take_input():
    x = input("Enter Input")
    return create.square(x)
```

And finally your **main.py**

```
from . import input
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip = input.take_input()
```

You will call the command -

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

And pyinstaller will import all the dependencies of all the files itself

Comment: Okay, going to check this.

Comment: In my program when login button is clicked it checks in database and then os.system ('mainwindow.exe') is called which should open the mainwindow but it is not opening while when I exit mainwindow then os.system ('loginform.exe') is called which works perfectly. Is this the right way to call the forms or not?

Comment: You'll have to debug the behaviour yourself. Your question said you wanted to build into one `exe` which happens with the answer above. Regarding this, it'd make sense to ask a new question as it will change the current question @MUHAMMADNABEELL1F14BSCS0108

Comment: Its done actually it was the problem of DB with Pyinstaller.

Comment: @NabeelAyub any lucky?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main_app.py
```

Comment: It only builds one executable of .py file.How I will connect multiples exe files?

Comment: Try running it. It will include all your modules

Comment: Run it on your main.py file

Comment: For Example: I have a login form which after verifying from database opens the main window form.It is working perfectly using command prompt as py files but not working with exe files.Moreover, when I import a main window in login form it doesn't work after creating executables.

Comment: Which file has all the imports ? run it on that file

Comment: Different forms are importing different forms... to use each others functions and data.

Comment: @MUHAMMADNABEELL1F14BSCS0108 Then you need to make a main.py that has all the import. After that run my command on it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Command `pyinstaller --onefile yourprogramname.py`. Pyinstaller will Automatically import and Compile the Dependency Files.

Comment: Including the third-party, uninstalled modules ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer. Check the command below

```
pyinstaller C:/version_0_1_client_server/scripts/filename.py --paths C:/version_0_1_client_server/  --add-data 'data/config.yaml;data' --add-data 'data/image.png;data'
```

---

File Structure:

```
Folder : version_0_1_client_server

    sub folder : 
                 data
                 scripts
```

data folder having png files and extra files.

---

I am using this command as it will take care of all .py file dependencies.

Comment: `-F` is shorthand for `--onefile`, so you don't need to supply both.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to edit the .spec file and run pyinstaller on the spec file instead of the individual .py files.

You can find information about adding multiple exes to as single .spec file here:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#multipackage-bundles

Comment: I re-read your question and I see that my solution does not exactly answer it, you still get multiple exes (but people running across your question may be looking for this answer).

Comment: No need to change spec file. I commented above we gonna give --path.