# making single executable if i have 2 guis (2 different python files) with pyinstaller

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable

I have a tkinter python code (main GUI) which calls another tkinter python code (child gui that provides input to main gui). I would like to know the trick to use pyinstaller in making a single executable that could compile both these guis.

Note: I have been successful in making executable with a tkinter python code (gui) that have a dependency (just .py file which is not a GUI).

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What will happened if you use `-F` in pyinstaller?

Comment: could you please provide some more help on using -F ? I have used --onefile and edited the specfile (to include the dependencies) afterwards.

Comment: Sure, I think it should work normally if you have used `--onefile`.What will happened?

Comment: ---onefile compiled just one gui but do not open second gui.

Comment: Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455765/build-multiple-py-files-into-a-single-executable-file-using-pyinstaller), it seems that `pyinstaller` will auto import the second gui when you pack it.