# How can I share a multifile python project as one file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file, executable

I have a python project with lots of other.py files it import from its sub folders and txt files as well
I want to share this project but only as one executable file so that Noone can see the code or the text files etc...
Is there any way to do so
If not how else can I share the project without letting anyone being able to check the code of the.py files

Answer (score 0):

You can user PyInstaller (https://www.pyinstaller.org/) to build a stand-alone executable.

Comment: Py installer still requires me to keep all the other py files that I'm importing and all the text files

Comment: @marsian8: Does [Build Multiple .py files into a single executable file using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455765/build-multiple-py-files-into-a-single-executable-file-using-pyinstaller) answer your question?