# Include an excel file in the executable file python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, executable

I need to import an excel template and then fill it with some info. The problem is that the template is not not accessible to all users and I need to put the template in the .exe file. I searched on the internet but I couldn't find the proper solution. Can you help me?

I import the template like this (with openpyxl)

```
location="C:/Users/aboriia/Desktop/Template ZA 50.xlsx"
Temp = openpyxl.load_workbook(location)
cbgsheet = Temp.get_sheet_by_name("CBG - 401 vs 501")
```

and then I fill the template

Comment: Can you create the template, using a new class or a structure like pandas? Yo don't really need to import it every time if it is not too complex.

Comment: it's pretty complex with a lot of formulas, the format should remain exactly the same, there are a lot of colours, borders and fonts

Comment: Here you have how to build an .exe from multiple files. If does not take the excel directly, save it using pickle and import it inside the program. If youhave problems, extend the question with more code and I'll try to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455765/how-to-build-multiple-py-files-into-a-single-executable-file-using-pyinstaller